# Detecting beacons in a background process in iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I want to run a background process that periodically gets a notification of beacons. The beacons are by default setup to transmit data every 500 ms. I only want my background process to get a notification every 5 minutes. The beacon's interval of transmitting can be adjusted, so I'm not sure if that is something I need to take into account when creating a background process. What isn't clear to me is how iOS detects what it calls beacon "updates". Reading the documentation, it almost sounds like the bluetooth framework only detects updates. What exactly are updates? The data being transmitted by the beacon is always the same, so no updates (that is, changes) are made.

So my question is, whether it's possible to have a background process detect bluetooth beacons at an interval but where the data from the beacon is always the same.

Answer (score 0):

Using CoreLocation to detect iBeacons on iOS, your app will only be woken up in the background when it detects a new beacon (`didEnterRegion`) or stops detecting that beacon (`didExitRegion`).

If you want your app to be woken up every 5 minutes by a beacon, you would need to have a beacon that turns on for a minute and then off for 4. I doubt whether you could buy a beacon that allows this sort of configuration, but you might be able to write a script that would make a computer advertise on this schedule.